# How to create aab instead of apk from Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to configure my personal app to be built as an android app bundle rather than apk in Jenkins. How do I configure my Jenkins to build aab and not apk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need **BundleTool** You can use bundletool to create an **aab** and sign it and even test it.
 You can install Bundletool just like another CLI utility and execute commands in **Jenkins**.

Or you can just execute a **Gradle** task like **bundleRelease** to generate your release aab.

[Here](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-part-2-bundletool-6705b50bea4c) is much detailed on how to do so.

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#bundletool-build
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

Comment: ` you can just execute a Gradle task like bundleRelease to generate your release aab.` where do i execute this command in jenkins. Im new to jenkins,should i add this in the build steps

Comment: in Jenkins CLI you can define commands to execute in terminal or shell, there you can try adding this one.

Comment: thanks. any idea what _assemble_ in gradle wrapper properties do?

Comment: i guess you are asking about gradle task assemble, it is used to generate apk file for different configurations and flavours so if you want to generate for release then it will be assembleRelease.

Comment: so in my case will it be okay to replace gradle task assemble with bundleRelease in jenkins cli

Comment: Yeah, it should work. Given the signing, configurations are already added in gradle file

Comment: Thanks.Is there anyway i can test my app in the mobile with the bundle uploaded in the play console

Comment: yeah there is a option in google play console to create internal test users and test the app before release works same for app bundle and apk, just read this fully they have explained this all.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195922/discussion-between-nari-and-vikas-kumar).

Comment: hi @vikaskumar, please, in your article you use the command "./gradlew bundleDebug"   how to install this command ""gradlew"" ???

Comment: ./gradlew is inside your android repo. you can execute it from your android project root folder @CamilaYamamoto

Comment: @vikaskumar ooh! that's true! it wasn't working becouse some how it was not executable!! tks!! I just create one debug .aab !

Comment: Hello everyone, today we faced an issue where suddenly build generated from using gradlew bundleRelease started crashing. We have just update our gradle to 6.1.1, BUT when we build using bundleTool it was working fine, we had a difference of 300kb in both the bundles bundletool was 7.8MB and gradlew bundleRelease was 7.5MB
We are using aab from past 1 year through jenkins gradlew bundleRelease, suddenly generated apk and aabs started crashing stating missing class files, then we saw this difference

Comment: In React Native in root folder cd android && ./gradlew bundleRelease